# Are Matrix messages encrypted using perfect forward secrecy?

Tags: forward-secrecy

I can not find it in the [FAQ](http://matrix.org/docs/guides/faq.html).

I know, that [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) has [PFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). But I am not interested in transport security but the message encryption of Matrix. Are the messages of Matrix encrypted with PFS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are (if you enable encryption, which has to be done manually).

End-to-End encryption in Matrix is done using the [OLM protocol](https://git.matrix.org/git/olm/about/docs/olm.rst) which is heavily based on the [Signal/Double Ratchet protocol](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/) and provides forward secrecy.

When you enable encryption for a matrix room for the first time, you can choose the degree to which new members of the room will be able to read messages written before they joined.

Answer (score 0):

No, not for rooms. Matrix does not have PFS for group chats. You are better with vpn and a mailing list if you need message archives. Asymetric cryptography is not designed for hanging exchanged symmetric passwords floating around. Even worse, a compromised server from the federated list can download the full logs as in cleartext. And matrix.org has just been hacked recently..Matrix is resilient, and can handle IRC-like splits, but it is defective by design regarding encrypted group chats where PFS and security is a must. Imagine sending sensitive documents in a room where a compromised server hosts some of the users.

Comment: Can you please clarify?  Do you believe that groups be fully end-to-end encrypted if this is enabled by the admin for all users, and can groups be secure assuming all client code is bug-free and backdoor-free?

Comment: This is just completely wrong. Please delete this answer.